# PKCS11# get certificate private key

Tags: pkcs#11

I would like to sign HttpWebRequest (c #) using a certificate stored on a smart card. Access to the private key only after the administration have PIN. 
I tried at the outset to connect using:
PKCS11-tool.exe --module enigmap11.dll --list-slots --list-objects --show-info --login --pin 1111 
Unfortunately it receives only identifier of the private key. 
Is using PKCS11-tool can somehow retrieve the private key and save the file * .der so as to attach the file to the HttpWebRequest c #? 
Or maybe you know some other method to download the private key but c #? I join the library enigmap11.dll maybe someone knows how to draw from it the method - it seems like pkcs11.dll.

[enigmap11.dll](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzolAfFiRUZBd3lwMkpKOVJXU2M/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

The sole purpose of a smart card is to prevent you from doing what you are trying to do.

You can never extract a private key from a smart card. Otherwise it wouldn't be a smart card.

Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: I'm newbie with certificates, I need this private key because I need to sign a file with this smart card certificate, is that possible ? Can you give me some explain?

Comment: @deFreitas You sign the file using the processor on the smart card, not on your own computer. You cannot extract the private key.

Answer (score 0):

Most devices won't let the key out of the device for security purposes, so you are out of luck here. If you need to use PKCS#11 in HTTPS, it's possible with the components offered by our SecureBlackbox (free licenses are available). With them you can use the certificate stored in the PKCS#11 device for client-side authentication of the TLS or HTTPS client.